# Microsoft Access not locking for editing

Tags: windows-8

My Access document is not stating "locked for editing" when I go in and someone else is in the document.  Afraid we are going to lose data if we are both in it and trying to save with another person is in the document.

Comment: Microsoft Access is designed to work with multiple users. It uses record locking mechanisms rather than file locking mechanisms so that users can edit different rows of the database but not the same row as someone else is editing. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208778

Comment: @Big Chris - should this not be an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Access is designed to work with multiple users. It uses record locking mechanisms rather than file locking mechanisms so that users can edit different rows of the database but not the same row as someone else is editing. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208778